# ConTeXt: Left aligned margin content

Tags: margins, context

I'm trying to get my margin content (flush)left aligned, but contrary to all examples and documentation I can find, this does not work:

```
\setuplayout[backspace=6cm,leftmargin=4cm,width=14cm]

\setupmargindata[inmargin][align=flushleft]

\starttext
\showframe
\inmargin{ 

\input ward 

\startitemize
  \item Something something this should be aligned just as if it was in the main text
  \item But it is not, it just looks weird and wrong.
\stopitemize

\externalfigure[cow.pdf][width=\marginwidth]

}

\input ward

\stoptext
```

[image]

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This here seems to do the trick:

```
\setuplayout[backspace=6cm,leftmargin=4cm,width=14cm]
\setupmarginframed[inmargin][align=flushleft]
\starttext
\showframe
\inmargin{

\input ward

\startitemize
  \item Something something this should be aligned just as if it was in the main text
  \item But it is not, it just looks weird and wrong.
\stopitemize

\externalfigure[cow.pdf][width=\marginwidth]

}

\input ward

\stoptext
```

[image]

Comment: It did, thank you! :-) Do you happen to know what options `setupmarginframed` is used for and which ones `setupmargindata`? I don't really understand the difference conceptually yet.